# section list of Object from c++ to ListView Section Delegate

Tags: c++, listview, qml, qt-creator, sections

I want to create a sectioned ListView in Qml from a list of Objects that create in c++ side from SQLite.
my SQLside code is:

```
QList<Threat *> app::SQLThreatControl::showThreatList()
{

    DataBase::instance()->connectDb();

    QSqlQuery show;

    show.exec("SELECT * FROM Threat ");

    QList<Threat *> *ThreatList = new QList<Threat *>;
    while (show.next()) {
        QString QuadAlt = show.value(1).toString();
        QString SerialNumber = show.value(2).toString();
        QString QuadHeight = show.value(3).toString();
        QString QuadLong = show.value(4).toString();
        QString QuadLat = show.value(5).toString();
        QString QuadSpeedLat = show.value(6).toString();
        QString QuadSpeedLong = show.value(7).toString();
        QString QuadSpeedHeight = show.value(8).toString();
        QString HomeLong = show.value(9).toString();
        QString HomeLat = show.value(10).toString();
        QString Type = show.value(11).toString();
        QString PilotLong = show.value(12).toString();
        QString PilotLat = show.value(13).toString();
        QString UUID = show.value(14).toString();
        QString date = show.value(15).toString();
        QString time = show.value(16).toString();
        QString User = show.value(17).toString();

        Threat *newThreat = new  Threat(  QuadAlt ,  SerialNumber,   UUID,  date,  time
                                          ,  User ,  PilotLong ,  PilotLat ,  Type ,  HomeLong ,  HomeLat
                                          ,  QuadHeight,  QuadLong , QuadLat  , QuadSpeedLat
                                          , QuadSpeedLong , QuadSpeedHeight);
        ThreatList->push_front(newThreat);
    }
    DataBase::instance()->closeDataBase();
    return *ThreatList;

}
```

my c++ code to send to front side:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void addThreatList(QList<Threat *> ThreatList) {

    itemHolder.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreatList.size(); i++) {
        Threat *obj = ThreatList.at(i);
        auto item = QSharedPointer<Threat>(obj);
        itemHolder.append(item);
    }
};
```

and my qml ListView code is:

```
    Provider{
        id:mpAllThreatProvider
    }

           ListView{
                id: listOfThreatHome
                layer.enabled: true
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: rectangle61.bottom
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.bottomMargin: 20
                anchors.leftMargin: 0
                anchors.rightMargin: 0
                anchors.topMargin: 10
                spacing: 10
                boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
                clip: true
                cacheBuffer: 3

                //model
                model: mpAllThreatProvider.itemHolder

                //delegate
                z : 5
                delegate:
                    ItemDeligateReportThreat {
                    mThreat:  mpAllThreatProvider.itemHolder.item(index)
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }

                section.property: mpAllThreatProvider.itemHolder.item(0).getSerialNumber()
                section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString

                section.delegate: SectionDeligateReportThreat{
                    mThreat:  mpAllThreatProvider.itemHolder.item(index)
                    
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
            }
```

I want to sort my Threats in the Qml section by SerialNumber of Quads and show threats details below in The section
The delegate itself is working correctly but the section part of ListView not
can you help me to do That?

Comment: What is `itemHolder`? What does it mean when you say the section part is not working? Are the fields already sorted correctly but without section headings? Sections do not sort, by the way. If you need to sort your list, you should look at [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html).

Comment: itemHolder is a property that send the list to Qml 

`Q_PROPERTY(QObjectListModel_Threat *itemHolder READ getHolder CONSTANT)
`
No I want just have a list of Quads Like That:


_SERIALNUM.1
___data 
___data

_SERIALNUM.2
___data 
___data